# php files connected with mysql server not working

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, wamp, lamp

I started a php project in netbeans and connected it with a database in `localhost/phpmyadmin`. But on running it gives this error on browser..

[image]

Why does this happen? How to avoid it?

Here are the codes in the project.. [dbconnect.php](http://ideone.com/Mls28l) and [index.php](http://ideone.com/CBNfP4). Files are saved in `/var/www/html/Testing/` (Testing is name of project).

Edit : I tried URL `localhost/Testing/index.php` but still gets the same error.
[image]

Edit2 : Folder structure of `/var/www`
[image]

Comment: I think your url is wrong... maybe `localhost/Testing/`

Comment: I changed the URL to `localhost/Testing/index.php/` but still get the error.

Comment: can you show screenshot of your folder structure

Comment: if you remove ./ from the include its working? on index.php, line "   include './DBConnect.php';"  if they are in the same folder , this must be working. Or with a simple index.html with only some text?

Comment: @rheese They aren't working either. HTML file works when opened with file URL but not with localhost URL as `localhost/Testing/index.html`

Comment: the port for localhost is ok? could you try localhost:8080/Testing...?

Answer (score 1):

Use path like `localhost/Testing/index.php`. Remove html folder from URL.

**Reason** ? Linux by default considers PHP files in html folder. So no need to give that folder name in url.

Comment: @vinay_Kumar , then pls post new screenshot of browser below current one in Edited question.

Answer (score 0):

type

```
localhost
```

in your browser, it must show you a page with all of the folders in your www directory.
then find your desirable folder and click on it, continue this until you get to your index.php file

Answer (score 0):

First try to access the localhost.
If all is well configured you will see there all projects.
Then access project that you need to see what gives you url

Answer (score 0):

Remove or rename
**.htaccess**
 the file from the project

you will able to open this project

Comment: Where do you htaccess in his project?

Comment: check out the testing folder, and remove .htaccess file.

Comment: Where is his -> testing folder ? I dont see it.